# How to use 'async def' in django views?

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, asgi

```
#views.py

async def test(request: ASGIRequest):
    return HttpResponse(b'hello')

class Test(View):
    async def get(self, request: ASGIRequest):
        print(type(request))
        print(dir(self))
        return HttpResponse(b'hello')
```

```
#urls.py

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path(r'testfunc/', test),
    path(r'testclass/', Test.as_view()),
]
```

I get this:

```
AttributeError at /testclass/
'coroutine' object has no attribute 'get'

##########

AttributeError at /testfunc/
'coroutine' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Answer (score 0):

In django 3.0, they started adding django support but this does not mean that we can use async views or middlewares.

Read more about it here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/async/

Answer (score 0):

Django 3.0 was the first step towards making it fully async-capable, but it will be a long journey. Async views are [not yet supported](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/async/), but they are expected later in the 3.x series.